# Python regular expression to replace blocks of whitespace with single character

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to replace blocks of white space with a single character. I have a possibly poorly formatted file and I would like to unify the delimiter for the data. For instance:

```
3,4  5\t6 \t 7            8 9
```

would then become:

```
3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Something similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868600/finding-columns-with-only-white-space-in-a-text-file-and-replace-them-with-a-uni) but for python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want regex:

```
    import re
    import sys
    line = sys.argv[1]
    re.sub(r'\s+', ',',line)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>string = '4  5\t6 \t 7            8 9'
>>','.join(string.split())
>>'4,5,6,7,8,9'
```

see: [Compress whitespaces in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496884/compress-whitespaces-in-string)

Comment: Thanks this is also a great answer. Very simple and pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
          string = "4  5\t6 \t 7            8 9"#your string
          a = string.split()
          print ', '.join(a)   #convert a list to string
```